# Is there any tool which can validate an ATL C++ code for COM Addref and Release rules

Tags: c++, com, window, atl

Is there any tool or source code analysis engine which when take a bunch of COM ATL projects, run through it and identify validate whether the COM rules for Addref and Release is followed correctly

Comment: ATL has built-in debugging facilities - see [`_ATL_DEBUG_INTERFACES`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sycfy8ec.aspx) and [`_ATL_DEBUG_QI`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7067t4w6.aspx). That's run-time analysis though, not static.

Answer (score 1):

You can just do text search for explicit `AddRef` and `Release` in code. These are all likely defects since ATL COM code base should use `CCOMPtr` and other ATL-based classes that do the ref-counting calls automatically. When you don't use `AddRef` and `Release` then the leaks remaining are ordinary memory leaks.

Comment: we do code review and put logs and print the return value of Release to check if is goes to zero, follow all COM addref and Release rules in code etc...but i am looking for tool for another round of verification.

Comment: I did mean that the ATL C++ code that contains AddRef or Release won't pass my review because it contains AddRef or Release that are not needed to be called directly in ATL C++ code.